# What does this mean. Certificate.... remote computer?

Tags: windows-10

Can anyone explain this to me? Does this mean a remote computer is accessing my computer.

[image: Certificate_Question]

Comment: This is just a properties dialog. It's about a certificate. That's all. Did you perhaps get some weird message on Facebook prompting you to do some steps?

Comment: No actually, my wife thinks I am spying on her and this was a question she posed to me. A little embarrassing, but all I can do is be honest.

Comment: Just do a little research via Google.... http://www.networksolutions.com/SSL-certificates/how-ssl-works.jsp and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority may help but search something like "how SSL certificates secure websites".... https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with Steve's answer at all.  (In fact, I suggest that you officially "accept" it, giving him the proper reward of recognition points ("reputation").  His answer was quite right.)  @PIMP_JUICE_IT 's comment was also quite nice to provide to you.  With some version of some popular browser, this could appear by double-clicking a "lock" icon.  (Whether that was/is Firefox or Chrome...  some of these details change so much I'm not keeping some of these details straight.)  All that was really meant to say is that the web browser is using a secure connection.

Answer (score 3):

No, this does not mean that a remote is accessing your computer.

As it says in the screen shot "Ensures the identity of a remote computer".  This means that with the issued certificate you can be confident that your computer is contacting its intended target, in your example this would be a server owned and authorized by facebook.com.

There is plenty of information out there on how SSL/TLS works.  You should start here in order to better understand what is going on and appeal to your curiosity.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realize that this may be somewhat of a remedial question to most on this site. I'm just trying to get some answers to questions as they come to me. Again, thanks for the info and advice.